# What is the Trustpilot API request limit?

Tags: trustpilot

I need to send multiple requests to the API to create invitation links for customers to review a company. Therefore, I'd like to know if there's a limit on the number of requests we can make? And if there are any, how many requests can be sent in an hour?

Answer (score 0):

There are some limits, but an exact threshold is not published. The following excerpt is taken from [Trustpilot's docs](https://documentation-apidocumentation.trustpilot.com/):

> While we do not publish a rate limiting policy, we do have certain limits to the usage of the APIs. For normal use cases this will not be an issue, but we will make sure that if our APIs are called at a more than reasonable rate, certain limits will apply.